# How to get CS2CS to recognize a 7-parameter Helmert shift (the +towgs parameter)

Tags: proj, cs2cs

I have defined a transformation from WGS84 to ETRS89 Poland CS92 (Epoch 2019.5) in CS2CS.

I can do the basic map projection, but the datum shift is being ignored. It doesn't matter what numbers I type in the +towgs parameter I get the same output.

Here is my CS2CS version:
Rel. 9.0.1, June 15th, 2022

And my command line:

```
echo 16d55'0.032"E 54d52'0.017"N | cs2cs +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs +datum=WGS84 +to +proj=tmerc +lon_0=19.0 +lat_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +k_0=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +units=m +towgs=0.895480,1.080270,-0.758180,-0.036560,0.018759,0.033366,-0.012400 +no_defs
366341.31       780117.83 0.00
```

Note that the result is wrong. It should be close to this:

```
366340.72       780117.32
```

It is not applying the 7-parameter shift. I have tried huge numbers in the X Y Z shift components and it doesn't change the output at all. What am I missing?